# Using the right pattern in react to add an id without passing it directly using props but through map?

Tags: reactjs

I have this code on **Codesandbox** the goal is to be able to pass 5 Divs, on load using use Effect.
and a second option to add a div on click when if the user feels like it. the code is partially working, but it has a anti-patter issue which is putting the component in the state instead of changing the state using map to pass the changes..
please take a look I would like to hear your opinion on this, what I do understand is importing the Div element like this could affect performance, I want to avoid bad practice as much as possible.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Div from "./Div";
import "./styles.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // on start add 5 divs in to the local state Array on the frist load
  });

  const [div, setDiv] = useState([]);

  const addDiv = () => {
    // add an extra div on click if needed with id using the right pattern
    setDiv([...div, <Div id={uuidv4()} />]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {div}
      <button onClick={addDiv} type="button">
        Click Me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
//Dev dependencise

"uuidv4": "6.2.12"
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-kare-8bwh4?file=/package.json:271-289)

Comment: What is the purpose of the ID?

Comment: ability to delete them later..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting JSX elements into state is a bad idea because they won't be *reactive* - you won't be able to (reliably) pass down state, state setters, and other useful things as props.

It's not so much a *performance* issue as a *code maintainability* issue - if you add additional functionality to your `Div` component and to your `App` you may find that your current approach won't work due to stale values that the JSX elements in state close over.

If you need the ability to delete a value, use the index of the div in the array and pass it down as needed. For a quick and dirty example:

```js
function App() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = React.useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTexts(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);
  }, []);
  const addDiv = () => {
    setTexts([...texts, text]);
    setText('');
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        texts.map((text, i) => (
          <div>
            <span>{text}</span>
            <button onClick={() => setTexts(texts.filter((_, j) => j !== i))}>delete</button>
          </div>
        ))
      }
      <button onClick={addDiv} type="button">
        Click Me!
      </button>
      <input value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Btw how to pass a component for the manner rather than text could you show me that part you are passing state here rather that a complicated component of HTML structure.

Comment: You mean pass down dynamic components for each rendered child? That sounds really really weird, do you mean like you'd want to be able to render, eg, `<Foo`, `<Bar`, `<Foo` as dynamic children based on input and remove them later? It'd involve `React.createElement` I think, but better to re-think that approach entirely IMO

Comment: If you want to keep from inlining the JSX, you can do something like `texts.map((text, i) => <TextComponent {...{ text, i, setTexts }} />)` and use those three props

Comment: @CertianParformance yes thanks this is the syntax :) I was looking for, but why would this inlining be bad ? extra renders ?

Comment: Inlining is OK for short things. Put it into a separate component for more complicated logic - easier maintainability and separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Just add id in the array and using `map` to render

```
{div.map(id => (
  <Div key={id} id={id} />
))}

const addDiv = () => {
  setDiv([...div, uuidv4()]);
};
```

Comment: Why do we need separate map to view the `div`s ? OP already storing complete `div`s inside the local state, not any data necessary to view inside the `div`. Therefore, what OP has done was right.

Comment: This is a not good solution. Because you have to save components on the array.

Comment: how to pass the component then ? rather than state

Comment: Yes, it's true. It is essential to keep data inside the local state that needs to be viewed in `div`s, not the complete `div` as OP did. But then why you do the same with **addDiv** method ?

Comment: just store id instead store all component